# Space removal on the left of image in Xml file in android studio using the recycler view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have two images that are beside textviews.

[image: UI]

Now the problem with this UI is that the images must be aligned to complete left side, as if coming out or sticking to the edge of the screen. However, that's not the case. I have tried `scaleType` and `adjustViewBound`, but both of them didn't work. The xml file contents have been shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_subtopic_title"
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView_bulb"
    android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Subtopic Title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_count"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView_subtopic_title"
    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
    android:text="Count"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="83dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_bulb"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulb_on" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_bulb"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="114dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_topic_title"
    android:layout_width="242dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="Topic Title" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/blue"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

What should be done to remove the space on the left of the images as shown in the image?

Comment: I suggest you ditch `RelativeLayout`, which (is/will be)  deprecated soon (according to the latest Google I/O 2018) in favor of ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Will that solve the problem?

Comment: Not directly, but it will give you the tools to work around it. Do you want to have an image start at the edge of the screen like with 0 space between the image and the edge?

Comment: Yes. I want no space between the edge and the image. It should be sticking to the edge.

Comment: use android:background="@drawable/bulb_on" instead of app:srcCompat="@drawable/bulb_on"

Comment: It has not worked. In fact it added an artifact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem. It basically lay with the `activity_main.xml`. The recyclerview in this xml had a left padding. I just removed it, made it 0. The snippet is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_Main"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I reduced the left margin to be zero in the attributes of the recyclerview.

Comment: If you mentioned that this is a recyclerview item layout, we would find the solution earlier. Anyway I'm glad you solved it

Comment: @mTak Thank you. I am sorry about not mentioning recyclerview because I did not think it was the problem. However, it turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is set negative margin:

```
android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
```

or

```
android:paddingStart="-10dp"
```

change -10 to what suits you.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/nodata"/>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I have tried with -10,-30,etc. The gap is still remaining.

Comment: Negative margins don’t always work (some vendor’s hack around it)

Comment: @Eswar did you test it in emulator or a real device?

Comment: @mTak I have tested on both. It didn't work on both.

Comment: I have tried padding. It does not work too. It looks like the background image also does not touch the edge.

Comment: @Eswar I have tested both margin and padding negative values in 4 different genymotion emulators and they work fine

Comment: @mTak Can you put up the snippet? It might be helpful.